# Order By length of a string

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is there a way to order this query by the length of the string contained in the **`Title`** field?

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
    SELECT b FROM AcmeTestBundle:Blog b
    WHERE b.Title LIKE :title'
    )->setParameter('title','%'.$title.'%');
```

`ORDER BY b.Title.length()` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does it give an error, or does it just not give the correct effect?

Comment: Thanks @meze but this doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just try:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT LENGTH(b.Title) l, b FROM AcmeTestBundle:Blog b WHERE b.Title LIKE :title ORDER BY l')->setParameter('title','%'.$title.'%');
```

Comment: @Patt it does. but you may need to upgrade to Doctrine 2.2+ and change the query a bit: LENGTH(b.Title) AS HIDDEN l. Otherwise you need to clean up the result.